# Filezilla server error - Couldn't load Tls libraries

Tags: server, filezilla

When i try to open filezilla server i get error like `Couldn't load Tls libraries`, how can i solve this error. How to install TLS Libraries file win 7 64bit.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 3):

https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=39838
According to the forum above, you need to install https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2533623.